# GitLab Runner register shows i/o timeout in Docker

Tags: docker, gitlab, containers, cicd, gitlab-runner

I'm trying to setup GitLab in my local machine and install GitLab and GitLab Runner in Docker:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                       PORTS                                                                                                         NAMES
f041339388c2   gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   19 minutes ago   Up 19 minutes                                                                                                                              gitlab-runner
c3a1e9b99f38   gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest       "/assets/wrapper"        46 hours ago     Up About an hour (healthy)   0.0.0.0:22->22/tcp, :::22->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, :::443->443/tcp   gitlab
```

Container inspect for `gitlab`:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "c3a1e9b99f383031c2ab60d55d5b51b6081cb14cd99eaffbfd59f13b283261fb",
        "Created": "2022-04-05T21:19:13.902999235Z",
        "Path": "/assets/wrapper",
        "Args": [],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 1533,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2022-04-07T17:53:01.529265764Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2022-04-06T21:58:58.315886026Z",
            "Health": {
                "Status": "healthy",
                "FailingStreak": 0,
                "Log": [
                    {
                        "Start": "2022-04-08T06:51:09.70727281+12:00",
                        "End": "2022-04-08T06:51:09.879538644+12:00",
                        "ExitCode": 0,
                        "Output": "OUTPUT PATH"
                    },
                    {
                        "Start": "2022-04-08T06:52:09.883781229+12:00",
                        "End": "2022-04-08T06:52:10.007407598+12:00",
                        "ExitCode": 0,
                        "Output": "OUTPUT PATH"
                    },
                    {
                        "Start": "2022-04-08T06:53:10.012089806+12:00",
                        "End": "2022-04-08T06:53:10.123264724+12:00",
                        "ExitCode": 0,
                        "Output": "OUTPUT PATH"
                    },
                    {
                        "Start": "2022-04-08T06:54:10.12809284+12:00",
                        "End": "2022-04-08T06:54:10.273646619+12:00",
                        "ExitCode": 0,
                        "Output": "OUTPUT PATH"
                    },
                    {
                        "Start": "2022-04-08T06:55:10.279143578+12:00",
                        "End": "2022-04-08T06:55:10.399512189+12:00",
                        "ExitCode": 0,
                        "Output": "OUTPUT PATH"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "Image": "sha256:9c00b5927bae442d3f8902f5c3bb58acb849fb1969d4ce85eb1699b3618729b8",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/c3a1e9b99f383031c2ab60d55d5b51b6081cb14cd99eaffbfd59f13b283261fb/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/c3a1e9b99f383031c2ab60d55d5b51b6081cb14cd99eaffbfd59f13b283261fb/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/c3a1e9b99f383031c2ab60d55d5b51b6081cb14cd99eaffbfd59f13b283261fb/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/c3a1e9b99f383031c2ab60d55d5b51b6081cb14cd99eaffbfd59f13b283261fb/c3a1e9b99f383031c2ab60d55d5b51b6081cb14cd99eaffbfd59f13b283261fb-json.log",
        "Name": "/gitlab",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "docker-default",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "/srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab",
                "/srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab",
                "/srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "22/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "22"
                    }
                ],
                "443/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "443"
                    }
                ],
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "always",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "host",
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 268435456,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4b28b6be75c79e41a90500a09d4493634e5fe95a1cdf38883c5bf3ad03c8ee02-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/2b3bc79dfce88dc46d755ac2a57da59518b3c42e9143d81b42cf504079c5d9c9/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/af25bc18d7ad1bca032219d6ed91de5c5c1eb585f59be7cdbdd6f87d9bfccb7c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9b057ce4d478064a7ad4cc7b82819412b6353adf09b5564951b38f5bd17bcb87/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b6028dcc6d0b368ff1491e7d81a12a90eef1f68ea825543919b4b5fd7f3ad68b/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/52ad6a00a274686a676a3c2f7c51e230fd3de77b9018dd9af9f73c26e143c547/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/21fa78d0cf6e3b07a8b846b7b6e625c8a674f6f3b94e06c17532587c9174e622/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/2dddf7eb7d91e36c86c873ad2577dab5ce095251f976995ca5d750595c9761fd/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6e52ab5f9066fe6d20c1985af0d505315977355ef34b3962142fd3cd665d0591/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4b28b6be75c79e41a90500a09d4493634e5fe95a1cdf38883c5bf3ad03c8ee02/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4b28b6be75c79e41a90500a09d4493634e5fe95a1cdf38883c5bf3ad03c8ee02/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4b28b6be75c79e41a90500a09d4493634e5fe95a1cdf38883c5bf3ad03c8ee02/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/srv/gitlab/config",
                "Destination": "/etc/gitlab",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            },
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/srv/gitlab/logs",
                "Destination": "/var/log/gitlab",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            },
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/srv/gitlab/data",
                "Destination": "/var/opt/gitlab",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "gitlab.example.com",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "22/tcp": {},
                "443/tcp": {},
                "80/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin:/opt/gitlab/bin:/assets:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "LANG=C.UTF-8",
                "EDITOR=/bin/vi",
                "TERM=xterm"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/assets/wrapper"
            ],
            "Healthcheck": {
                "Test": [
                    "CMD-SHELL",
                    "/opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-healthcheck --fail --max-time 10"
                ],
                "Interval": 60000000000,
                "Timeout": 30000000000,
                "Retries": 5
            },
            "Image": "gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest",
            "Volumes": {
                "/etc/gitlab": {},
                "/var/log/gitlab": {},
                "/var/opt/gitlab": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "57128e6ffed42d70c4979dd5021f063d8426c5f95ae4f5f60791f302b991d455",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "22/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "22"
                    },
                    {
                        "HostIp": "::",
                        "HostPort": "22"
                    }
                ],
                "443/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "443"
                    },
                    {
                        "HostIp": "::",
                        "HostPort": "443"
                    }
                ],
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    },
                    {
                        "HostIp": "::",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/57128e6ffed4",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "5304f85f8b4fcf9e4b6e3febeef987e89cc71338132b7624e44d7e3e6f7466dc",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "9de2792fcb1439008ecc6412483f657c2d958f20c681782525f209e12f4c2dc3",
                    "EndpointID": "5304f85f8b4fcf9e4b6e3febeef987e89cc71338132b7624e44d7e3e6f7466dc",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                },
                "gitlab-network": {
                    "IPAMConfig": {},
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "c3a1e9b99f38",
                        "gitlab.example.com"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "91536b80663973f3e96ea988a398763627d8678b90897c9c2af2234e4850f568",
                    "EndpointID": "2b53bcd1b619c68d69fb9bcab8db3ab763c3808ed3a466b378e1a4323f76cb48",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.18.0.3",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
                    "DriverOpts": {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Container inspect for `gitlab-runner`:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "f041339388c240b147ee82658dbe33feca8f73d556d208ac8aca303199895ed8",
        "Created": "2022-04-07T18:33:41.706840368Z",
        "Path": "/usr/bin/dumb-init",
        "Args": [
            "/entrypoint",
            "run",
            "--user=gitlab-runner",
            "--working-directory=/home/gitlab-runner"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 11086,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2022-04-07T18:33:41.971920584Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:9b9fc292da4ab1898e96ebccba7b70d28996c7ba97782743ceb6508253856fb7",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/f041339388c240b147ee82658dbe33feca8f73d556d208ac8aca303199895ed8/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/f041339388c240b147ee82658dbe33feca8f73d556d208ac8aca303199895ed8/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/f041339388c240b147ee82658dbe33feca8f73d556d208ac8aca303199895ed8/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/f041339388c240b147ee82658dbe33feca8f73d556d208ac8aca303199895ed8/f041339388c240b147ee82658dbe33feca8f73d556d208ac8aca303199895ed8-json.log",
        "Name": "/gitlab-runner",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "docker-default",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "/srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner",
                "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "gitlab-network",
            "PortBindings": {},
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "always",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "host",
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/962a04960331a5d6282b9f5a673184560d5d668183137a373e3671346dc5a764-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1ed4db10a6e68c0c4fc9f902d1dcd74a94a4b6d26a159df5214256ea605a1c7e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c2d172e960e7aca15c2564e86302418b14838cf976b74d11312281327e0dd437/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6e52ab5f9066fe6d20c1985af0d505315977355ef34b3962142fd3cd665d0591/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/962a04960331a5d6282b9f5a673184560d5d668183137a373e3671346dc5a764/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/962a04960331a5d6282b9f5a673184560d5d668183137a373e3671346dc5a764/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/962a04960331a5d6282b9f5a673184560d5d668183137a373e3671346dc5a764/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "83f4f2d800709ce627753a2e086f965e40b8bf51bbc85fab91ddfc98f8e4f31e",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/83f4f2d800709ce627753a2e086f965e40b8bf51bbc85fab91ddfc98f8e4f31e/_data",
                "Destination": "/home/gitlab-runner",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            },
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/srv/gitlab-runner/config",
                "Destination": "/etc/gitlab-runner",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            },
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/var/run/docker.sock",
                "Destination": "/var/run/docker.sock",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "f041339388c2",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "run",
                "--user=gitlab-runner",
                "--working-directory=/home/gitlab-runner"
            ],
            "Image": "gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest",
            "Volumes": {
                "/etc/gitlab-runner": {},
                "/home/gitlab-runner": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/usr/bin/dumb-init",
                "/entrypoint"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {},
            "StopSignal": "SIGQUIT"
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "ca7e0de2c2cc29fa673eb196bedca2b44d23e5f86d7f7ed6cde27593c8b0272e",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {},
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/ca7e0de2c2cc",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "gitlab-network": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "f041339388c2"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "91536b80663973f3e96ea988a398763627d8678b90897c9c2af2234e4850f568",
                    "EndpointID": "7943e697deb3890b39afd71175ca8c7df92e96e5952d725f64b7475c15c12025",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.18.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

From host machine I'm able to access `gitlab` using http://172.18.0.3/ and the only part which is left is registering the `gitlab-runner` but while I'm doing this part I'm getting I/O timeout error

```
$ sudo docker run --rm -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner gitlab/gitlab-runner register \
>   --non-interactive \
>   --executor "docker" \
>   --docker-image alpine:latest \
>   --url "http://172.18.0.3/" \
>   --registration-token "GR1348941z4tNrqhtAWm2-HTNzqPd" \
>   --description "docker-runner" \
>   --maintenance-note "Free-form maintainer notes about this runner" \
>   --tag-list "docker,aws" \
>   --run-untagged="true" \
>   --locked="false" \
>   --access-level="not_protected"
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=7 revision=bd40e3da version=14.9.1
Running in system-mode.                            
                                                   
ERROR: Registering runner... failed                 runner=GR134894 status=couldn't execute POST against http://172.18.0.3/api/v4/runners: Post "http://172.18.0.3/api/v4/runners": dial tcp 172.18.0.3:80: i/o timeout
PANIC: Failed to register the runner.
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker containers started separately cannot communicate with each other unless their networks are explicitly linked. That is why you are getting an I/O error from your runner container.

To address this issue, either attach both containers to the same docker network (docker-compose makes this easy) or use host networking (`--network=host`) when running both containers and use localhost as the GitLab URL and registration target.

Additional reference:

- Docker [networking tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/networkingcontainers/)
- Docker [compose reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links) (see `links:`, `aliases:` and `networks:`)
- Docker [network connect](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_connect/)

Comment: I have created new network "gitlab-network" and added both of the container to it so network is like this

Gitlab: 172.18.0.3
Gitlab-runner: 172.18.0.2
Gateway: 172.18.0.1

And still has the same issue